# Unable to call config-server from client

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am doing a POC on spring cloud server config. My config server is all up and running in *https://localhost:8888/* port. Now I have build a client to read config properties from config-server. Below are the file details:

**application.properties**

```
spring.application.name = config-client
spring.config.import = optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
#backup value
config-client.value=99
```

**application.yml**

```
server.port: 8080

spring:
  application.name: config-client
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: refresh
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:7001/eureka/
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 1
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>config-client</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netflix-candidates</id>
            <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
            <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Upon running client I am getting the below error:

```
I:\ds\tools\jdk17\latest\bin\java.exe -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:C:\JPMC\DEV\TMP\ds\tools\idea2021.3\latest\lib\idea_rt.jar=53210:C:\JPMC\DEV\TMP\ds\tools\idea2021.3\latest\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath I:\GitCode\configServerPOC\config-client\target\classes;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-actuator\3.0.2\spring-boot-starter-actuator-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.0.2\spring-boot-starter-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.0.2\spring-boot-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.0.4\spring-context-6.0.4.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.0.4\spring-aop-6.0.4.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.0.4\spring-expression-6.0.4.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.0.2\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.0.2\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.5\logback-classic-1.4.5.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.5\logback-core-1.4.5.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.19.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.19.0.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.19.0\log4j-api-2.19.0.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.6\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.6.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.33\snakeyaml-1.33.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure\3.0.2\spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-actuator\3.0.2\spring-boot-actuator-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.14.1\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.10.3\micrometer-observation-1.10.3.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.10.3\micrometer-commons-1.10.3.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-core\1.10.3\micrometer-core-1.10.3.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\hdrhistogram\HdrHistogram\2.1.12\HdrHistogram-2.1.12.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\latencyutils\LatencyUtils\2.0.3\LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-starter-config\4.0.1\spring-cloud-starter-config-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-starter\4.0.1\spring-cloud-starter-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-context\4.0.1\spring-cloud-context-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\6.0.1\spring-security-crypto-6.0.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-commons\4.0.1\spring-cloud-commons-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-rsa\1.0.11.RELEASE\spring-security-rsa-1.0.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcpkix-jdk15on\1.69\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.69.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.69\bcprov-jdk15on-1.69.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcutil-jdk15on\1.69\bcutil-jdk15on-1.69.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-config-client\4.0.1\spring-cloud-config-client-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.0.4\spring-web-6.0.4.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.0.4\spring-beans-6.0.4.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.14.1\jackson-annotations-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\client5\httpclient5\5.1.4\httpclient5-5.1.4.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\core5\httpcore5\5.1.5\httpcore5-5.1.5.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\core5\httpcore5-h2\5.1.5\httpcore5-h2-5.1.5.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.15\commons-codec-1.15.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.14.1\jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.14.1\jackson-core-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client\4.0.0\spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client\4.0.0\spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\com\netflix\eureka\eureka-client\2.0.0\eureka-client-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\com\netflix\netflix-commons\netflix-eventbus\0.3.0\netflix-eventbus-0.3.0.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\com\netflix\netflix-commons\netflix-infix\0.3.0\netflix-infix-0.3.0.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\commons-jxpath\commons-jxpath\1.3\commons-jxpath-1.3.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.3\joda-time-2.3.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr-runtime\3.4\antlr-runtime-3.4.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\antlr\stringtemplate\3.2.1\stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.9.1\gson-2.9.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math\2.2\commons-math-2.2.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream\1.4.19\xstream-1.4.19.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\io\github\x-stream\mxparser\1.2.2\mxparser-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\xmlpull\xmlpull\1.1.3.1\xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\jakarta\ws\rs\jakarta.ws.rs-api\3.1.0\jakarta.ws.rs-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.1\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\com\netflix\servo\servo-core\0.12.21\servo-core-0.12.21.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\19.0\guava-19.0.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.14\httpclient-4.5.14.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.16\httpcore-4.4.16.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.10\commons-configuration-1.10.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.4.0\jettison-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\com\netflix\eureka\eureka-core\2.0.0\eureka-core-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\jakarta\servlet\jakarta.servlet-api\6.0.0\jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\woodstox\woodstox-core\6.2.1\woodstox-core-6.2.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\stax2-api\4.2.1\stax2-api-4.2.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer\4.0.1\spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-loadbalancer\4.0.1\spring-cloud-loadbalancer-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\reactor-core\3.5.2\reactor-core-3.5.2.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.4\reactive-streams-1.0.4.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\addons\reactor-extra\3.5.0\reactor-extra-3.5.0.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-cache\3.0.2\spring-boot-starter-cache-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\6.0.4\spring-context-support-6.0.4.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\com\stoyanr\evictor\1.0.0\evictor-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.6\slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.0.4\spring-core-6.0.4.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.0.4\spring-jcl-6.0.4.jar;C:\Users\V778153\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.24\lombok-1.18.24.jar com.example.configserver.ConfigClientApplication
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.2)

2023-02-13T16:49:40.955+05:30  INFO 22964 --- [           main] c.e.c.ConfigClientApplication            : Starting ConfigClientApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 22964 (I:\GitCode\configServerPOC\config-client\target\classes started by V778153 in I:\GitCode\configServerPOC\config-client)
2023-02-13T16:49:40.957+05:30  INFO 22964 --- [           main] c.e.c.ConfigClientApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-02-13T16:49:40.988+05:30  INFO 22964 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2023-02-13T16:49:40.988+05:30  INFO 22964 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Located environment: name=config-client, profiles=[default], label=null, version=6e82569dc3593afe5ed2c1e2a057327107670f71, state=null
2023-02-13T16:49:41.373+05:30  WARN 22964 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.example.configserver.ConfigClientApplication]: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2023-02-13T16:49:41.386+05:30  INFO 22964 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-02-13T16:49:41.409+05:30 ERROR 22964 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.example.configserver.ConfigClientApplication]: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:524) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:726) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:723) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:694) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:182) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:398) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:283) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:745) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at com.example.configserver.ConfigClientApplication.main(ConfigClientApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:211) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:48) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:936) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:379) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:325) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:365) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:265) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:514) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    ... 18 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after reading through [Eureka documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/docs/current/reference/html/) I noticed the Application file uses a SpringApplicationBuilder, so I changed mine to this and it runs and registers without issues.

```
public class StagingBuilderApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(StagingBuilderApplication.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
    }
}
```